# Can I convert this extension method to use IDbSet<> instead of DbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, extension-methods

Currently I use the below method like this: `db.GetProjectsAllowed(profileId, profOrgList, projectList)`. I would like to convert this to use `IDbSet<Project>`, but I'm not sure how to get the second LINQ query.

```
public static IQueryable<Project> GetProjectsAllowed
(
    this IMkpContext db,
    Guid profileId,
    List<Guid> profOrgIds = null,
    List<Guid> projectIds = null
)
{
    var projects = 
        (
            from p in db.Project
                .Include(p => p.Proposals)
                .Include(p => p.RoleAssignments)
                .Include("RoleAssignments.AssigneeSnapshot")
            where p.IsActive
            select p);

    if (profOrgIds != null && profOrgIds.Any())
    {
        var profileIds = db.ProfileOrganization
            .Where(po => po.IsActive && profOrgIds.Contains(po.OrganizationId))
            .Select(po => po.ProfileId);
        projects = projects.Where(p => profileIds.Contains(p.CreatedById));
    }

    if (projectIds != null && projectIds.Any())
        projects = projects.Where(proj => projectIds.Contains(proj.ProjectId));

    return projects;//.ToList();
}
```

Can I convert this to use `IDbSet<Project>` or not?

Comment: Of course you could but you would have to pass in the ProfileOrganisation property as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1):

Here, why not split this into two extension methods? This makes your `GetProjectsAllowed` extension method more [cohesive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and [single responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

**First**:

```
public static IEnumerable<Guid> GetProfileIds(
    this IDbSet<ProfileOrganization> profileOrganizations,
    IEnumerable<Guid> profOrgIds = null)
{
    return profOrgIds == null ? null :
        from po in profileOrganizations
        where po.IsActive
        where profOrgIds.Contains(po.OrganizationId)
        select po.OrganizationId;
}
```

And **second**:

```
public static IQueryable<Project> GetProjectsAllowed(
    this IDbSet<Project> projects, 
    IEnumerable<Guid> profileIds, 
    IEnumerable<Guid> projectIds = null)
{
    var activeProjects =
        from project in projects
        //.Include(..
        where project.IsActive
        select project;

    if (profileIds != null && profileIds.Any())
    {
        activeProjects = activeProjects.Where(p => profileIds.Contains(p.CreatedById));
    }

    if (projectIds != null && projectIds.Any())
    {
        activeProjects = activeProjects.Where(proj => projectIds.Contains(proj.ProjectId));
    }

    return activeProjects;//.ToList();
}
```

And then the consumer can call it like this:

```
var profileIds = db.ProfileOrganization.GetProfileIds(profOrgIds);
var projectsAllowed = db.Projects.GetProjectsAllowed(profileIds, projectIds);
```